# For a semisimple algebra and two $M$- and $W$-homogeneous parts for $M \ncong W$, why we have $M(A)W(A) = 0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $F$ be a field and $A$ be an $F$-vector space which is also a ring with $1$. Suppose for all $c \in F$ and $x,y \in A$ we have
$$
 (cx)y = c(xy) = x(cy)
$$
Then $A$ is called an $F$-algebra. If for an $F$-algebra $A$ we have some finite-dimensional $F$-vector space such that for each $v \in V$ and $x \in A$ there is a unique $vx \in V$ defined such that for $x,y \in A, v, w \in V$ and $c \in F$ we have

- $(v+w)x = vx + wx$
- $v(x+y) = vx + vy$
- $(vx)y = v(xy)$
- $(cv)x = c(vx) = v(cx)$
- $v1 = v$

then $V$ is an $A$-module. If $A$ is any algebra, then $A$ itself is an $A$-module under right multiplication. This module is called the *regular* $A$-module and denoted by $A^{\circ}$. For an $A$-module we call $W \subseteq V$ an $A$-*submodule* if $W$ is a linear subspace that is also $A$-invariant, i.e. $wx \in W$ for $w \in W, x \in A$. An $A$-module is called *completely reducible* if for every $A$-submodule $W \subseteq V$ there exists another $A$-submodule $U$ such that $V = W + U$, $W \cap U = \{0\}$. An algebra $A$ is called *semisimple* if its regular module $A^{\circ}$ is completely reducible. A nonzero $A$-module $V$ is called *irreducible* if $\{0\}$ and $V$ are its only submodules. As it turns out, for an $F$-algebra $A$, every irreducible $A$-module is isomorphic to a factor module of $A^{\circ}$, and further if $A$ is semisimple, then every irreducible $A$-module is isomorphic to a submodule of $A^{\circ}$.

Let $V$ be a completely reducible $A$-module and let $M$ be an irreducible $A$-module. The $M$-homogeneous part of $V$, denotes $M(V)$, is the sum of all those submodules of $V$ which are isomorphic to $M$. If $W \ncong M$ then it follows that $M(A) \cap W(A) = 0$.

Now I have a question on the following proof:

> Let $A$ be a semisimple algebra and let $M$ be an irreducible $A$-module. If $W$ is irreducible, then it is annihilated by $M(A)$ unless $W \cong M$.

Proof: If $W$ is an irreducible $A$-module with $W \ncong M$, then $W(A) \cap M(A) = 0$ by the above remark. Since $W(A)$ and $M(A)$ are ideals, we have $W(A)M(A) = 0$. By the above remarks, $A^{\circ}$ has a submodule $W_0 \cong W$ and $W_0 \subseteq W(A)$, so that $M(A)$ annihilates $W_0$. Since $W \cong W_0$, they have the same annihilator in $A$ and the statement follows. $\square$

I do not understand that why we have $W(A)M(A) = 0$ in the above proof. I found the result that for ideals $I, J$ in a ring $R$, that if $I + J = R$ (i.e. both ideals are coprime) then we have $I\cdot J = I \cap J$. But I do not know if that applies here, as I do not see that $M(A)$ and $W(A)$ are coprime. So why does the above hold?

These definitions and statement are taken from [I. Martin Isaacs, Character Theory of Finite Groups](https://books.google.de/books?id=KtiFfQ0uImsC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), Chapter 1. Specifically my question concerns Theorem 1.15 (Wedderburn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of two ideals is always contained in their intersection (even if they are not coprime), so that $W(A)M(A)\subseteq W(A)\cap M(A)=0$.